# The first fundamental theorem of calculus

Tags: calculus

If

\begin{align*}
F(x) = \int_{0}^x \left\lbrace  t \int_{0}^t f(u) \text{ d}u       \right\rbrace \text{ dt}.
\end{align*}
Find: $F^{\prime}(-1)$, $F^{\prime}(0)$, $F^{\prime\prime}(1/2)$ and $F^{\prime\prime}(1/2)$.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: I can see that you (probably) mistakenly wrote $F''(1/2)$ instead of $F'''(1/2)$ at the end.  Do you still need the last thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$F'(x)=x\int_0^xf(u)\ du, \ \  F'(-1)=\int_{-1}^0f(u) \ du.$$

$$F''(x)=\frac d{dx}\left[x\int_0^xf(u)\ du\right]=\int_0^xf(u)\ du+xf(x),$$
$$F''(0)=0, \ \ F''\left(\frac12\right)=\int_0^{\frac12}f(u)\ du+\frac12f\left(\frac12\right).$$